# Docker, Corporate Proxy (using PX Reverse Proxy) fails to do DNS lookup when adding new packages within Dockerfile with 'apk add'

Tags: docker, dns, dockerfile, reverse-proxy, ntlm

I started to work with Docker within our Company and have a network issue within my Docker Desktop.

my system setup is:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Docker Desktop (4.3.2)
- Corporate Proxy to connect to the Internet
- [PX Proxy (0.5.0)](https://github.com/genotrance/px/releases/tag/v0.5.0) as Reverse Proxy which is as default running on Port 3128.

I simply tried out to dockerize the sample node.js application from the [getting-started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) by following Dockers instructions, which is failing for me to build due to the
`RUN apk add...` (see below)

step.

*First try*: `docker build -t getting-started .` which should usually do the simple thing.

Result is: ***DNS lookup error*** in the `RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make` instruction.
It seems that calling the internet from inside the Dockerfile is not a trivial thing :-(.

Output:[image]

*Second try*: `docker build -t getting-started . --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128 --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128`

This time I am getting ***network error (check Internet connection and firewall)*** also in the same step.

Output:[image]

My **Dockerfile** looks as same as in the tutorial.

```dockerfile
FROM node:12-alpine
# Adding build tools to make yarn install work on Apple silicon / arm64 machines
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

In the same directory i have the sample application, just as described in the mentioned getting-started tutorial.

**px.ini file:**

```ini
[proxy]
server = my.company.com:8080
port = 3128
listen = 127.0.0.1
gateway = 1
hostonly = 0
noproxy = 127.0.0.*,10.*.*.*,192.168.*.*
allow = *.*.*.*
username= de\username
 
[settings]
workers = 3
threads = 8
idle = 30
socktimeout = 20.0
foreground = 0
log = 0
```

Docker Desktop Proxies Configuration:
[image]

Many research in the web as e.g. here at stackoverflow, in forums, etc. I found the hint that it could be very likely a network configuration problem.

Does anybody know, what I am doing wrong here?
How should Docker correctly setup with a corporate proxy and a Reverse Proxy as CNTLM or PX Proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my problem by using environment variables also within the Dockerfile.

```
    FROM node:12-alpine

    ARG http_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128
    ARG https_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128

    # Adding build tools to make yarn install work on Apple silicon / arm64 
    machines
    RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    RUN yarn install --production
    CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following 2 lines in the dockerfile helped me to resolve this issue.

```
ARG http_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128
ARG https_proxy=http://host.docker.internal:3128
```